# Fill in a 2**n square grid with triominoes recursively?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that can fill in a square grid of size 2**n x 2**n that has one square removed with triominoes (L-shaped pieces that take up three squares).

The parameters of the function are `n` (board  size is 2**n), `removed_row`, and `removed_column`.
The board is a list of lists initially all set to 0.  Then I set the removed square to a global count variable (which is 1 initially) and then increment the count.

So what I would like is: if `n == 2` then the board should look like this after the function has been called:

```
[[4, 1, 3, 3]
 [4, 4, 2, 3]
 [5, 2, 2, 6]
 [5, 5, 6, 6]]
```

Where 1 is the removed square and 2 thru 6 are triominoes.

I know how to solve this problem recursively, I'm just having trouble putting it into code.

Basically I want to divide the board into 4 quadrants 1, 2, 3, and 4 (1 referring to the top right quadrant and 4 referring to the bottom right quadrant). Then put a triominoe that fills a square of each of the quadrants that do not already have a square filled in or missing. Then repeat this process on each of the quadrants until all of the squares are not equal to zero.

Here is my code that I think should work but I obviously went wrong somewhere because the only case it works for is `n == 1`:

```
count = 1

def triominoes(n, removed_row=0, removed_column=0) :
    global count
    # initialization of the board:
    board = [ [0] * 2**n for i in range(2**n) ]

    # code for generating the board goes here
    # you can (and are encouraged to) use recursive helper function/s

    #Set the removed square to 1:
    board[removed_row][removed_column] = count
    count+=1    

    if (n==1):
        for row in range(len(board)) :
            for col in range(len(board[row])) :
                if (board[row][col] == 0) :
                    board[row][col] = count
        return board

    #Call the helper function on each sub-board
    triominoes_helper((n-1), removed_row, removed_column, 1, board) #Quadrant 1
    triominoes_helper((n-1), removed_row, removed_column, 2, board) #Quadrant 2
    triominoes_helper((n-1), removed_row, removed_column, 3, board) #Quadrant 3
    triominoes_helper((n-1), removed_row, removed_column, 4, board) #Quadrant 4

    return board




#def recursive_helper()
def triominoes_helper(n, removed_row, removed_column, location, board) :
    global count
    #Base Case
    if (n==1):
        for row in range(len(board)) :
            for col in range(len(board[row])) :
                if (board[row][col] == 0) :
                    board[row][col] = count
        return board

    #Recursive Case
    if (location == 1) :
        if (not is_removed(n, location, board)) :
            board[2**(n-1)-1][2**(n-1)] = count
    elif (location == 2) :
        if (not is_removed(n, location, board)) :
            board[2**(n-1)-1][2**(n-1)-1] = count
    elif (location == 3) :
        if (not is_removed(n, location, board)) :
            board[2**(n-1)][2**(n-1)-1] = count
    else :
        if (not is_removed(n, location, board)) :
            board[2**(n-1)][2**(n-1)] = count
    count+=1

    triominoes_helper(n-1, 2**(n-1)-1, 2**(n-1), 1, board)
    triominoes_helper(n-1, 2**(n-1)-1, 2**(n-1)-1, 2, board)
    triominoes_helper(n-1, 2**(n-1), 2**(n-1)-1, 3, board)
    triominoes_helper(n-1, 2**(n-1), 2**(n-1), 4, board)

#Function to see if a sub-board already has a square removed
def is_removed(n, location, board) :
    if (location == 1) :
        for r in range(0, 2**(n-1)-1) :
            for c in range(2**(n-1), 2**n-1) :              
                if (board[r][c] != 0) :
                    return True

    elif (location == 2) :
        for r in range(0, 2**(n-1)-1) :
            print(r)
            for c in range(0, 2**(n-1)-1) :
                print(c)

                if (board[r][c] != 0) :
                    return True

    elif (location == 3) :
        for r in range(2**(n-1), 2**n-1) :
            for c in range(0, 2**(n-1)-1) :
                if (board[r][c] != 0) :
                    return True

    else :
        for r in range(2**(n-1), 2**n-1) :
            for c in range(2**(n-1), 2**n-1) :
                if (board[r][c] != 0) :
                    return True

    return False




print(triominoes(2))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Think about the base case in your `triominoes_helper`. What is it supposed to do? For `triominoes(2)`, when `triominoes_helper` is called with n=1, it immediately clobbers the entire board (replacing every 0 in the 4x4 board with 2s). Then it's called again 3 times, with no change. Is that what you want?